How to overwrite part of a binary file?
I want to process a binary file and write the results into a new one of the same format.
My code starts by copying the header, and, for each data frame, load/process/output it:
      program main
      use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: int32, real32
      implicit none

      integer(kind=int32),dimension(:),allocatable :: header
      real(kind=real32),dimension(:),allocatable :: frame

      integer(kind=int32) nb_frames, frame_sz
      integer i

      allocate(header(256))

      open(unit=1,file='fort.1',access='stream',status='old')
      read(1) header

      frame_sz = header(1)
      nb_frames = header(2)
      allocate(frame(frame_sz))

      open(unit=2,file='fort.2',access='stream',status='new')
      write(2) header

      do i=1,nb_frames
          read(1) frame
C ...     some calculations
          write(2) frame
      enddo

      close(unit=1)

C ... PLACEHOLDER: update a few values in the header of unit #2

      close(unit=2)
      deallocate(header)
      deallocate(frame)

      end

After processing the whole input file I need to update the header in the outputted file. How would you do it?

You can use non-standard (gnu extension) call fseek(file_unit, 0, 0, ierr) of gfortran to return file position pointer to start of the file and write header again. other fortran implementations may have similar extensions.

@GhorbanM.Tavakoly does writing the new header after fseeking truncate the file (ie. the data after the header is lost)?

no. it just overwrites the header. see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FSEEK.html

Can you explain the format of the header? (This doesn't need to be exact, but if the header is not of fixed size, for example, the impact is huge.)

As your file is connected for stream access, though, there's no reason to use nonsense like non-standard file positioning statements: write(..., pos=...).

@francescalus the header has a fixed 1024 bytes size and can have optional fields; I won't be adding nor removing any of those fields.

@francescalus thank you, I'll try the write( ..., pos=...) later.

+1 for @francescalus separate post as answer to this post. rewind is in standard fortran 2003 (section 9.7.3) and preferable to my fseek suggestion.

+1 for @francescalus separate post as answer to this post. rewind is in standard fortran 2003 (section 9.7.3) and preferable to my fseek suggestion.

How much data are you talking about - a few K or Gigabytes?  If it is not much data then just do all your manipulations in memory and then write everything out at the end.

@cup The size of those files can vary a lot; from a few hundreds MB to a few tens of GB.

If an external file has a defined position, the next data transfer statement involving that file starts at the next position. You can position a file at its initial point using the rewind statement:
rewind(unit)
write(unit=2, ...) ! Transfer starting from the initial point

In terms of overwriting, the impact of a write to a file positioned at its initial, or other, point depends on the access mode of the external file:

a write to a sequentially connected file is liable to be followed by the implicit write of an endfile record
records for a directly connected file are overwritten and there's no jeopardy that an endfile record be written
file storage units of a stream file are overwritten and records don't exist

For a sequentially connected file, the effect of an endfile record is to truncate (subsequent records are no longer considered to exist).
All that's to say: if you have a stream access file, you can (over)write arbitrary file storage units. You needn't even rewind:
write(unit=2, pos=1, ...)

If you need to write more data at an earlier point in a file, you are out of luck:

a direct access file will hit an end-of-record condition
a stream access file will overwrite subsequent file storage units

